# My selection "hacks" or shortcuts aren´t working

Tags: edges, shortcut, selection-tools

When you are in edit mode and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> while clicking on an edge it will select all edges that make a loop, the same with faces, right?
Well, in my office PC it is the case but something happened in my home PC Blender version that all of the sudden I have to click EVERY single edge or face to select them.

Where can I edit preferences or change whatever went wrong?
I installed another version of Blender and it persists, is it something external to Blender?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide an examplary screenshot of the area you want to select?
There are certain objects that look like, but don't actually have edges that are connected to a loop. To single out this possibility, it's important to know what you were trying to select.

You could try to reset the Blender settings to factory settings.
To do this, you go *File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings*.

[image]

When installing a new Blender version, it is possible to port old settings to the new version, for convenience sake. This could have led to transporting possible faulty setting changes to persist.

Please also make sure your <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is working properly. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and see if that works globally on your device. If it does, we can rule out a hardware issue in your case.

For further investigation, it's likely you need to observe this a bit further and find out if there is anything else not working. For example, what's the exact situation you try to select a loop, are you in edge or vertex selection mode and not in face select. Or you might have an addon that changes things, list your addons if that's the case. Try to find patterns. Also, when did you last remember to be able to loop select? When did it start to not work anymore?

Hope this helps.